# Vapor Linux Build with SwiftyBeaver Failing

Tags: docker, vapor, swiftybeaver

I've been trying to build my Vapor Project using Docker. I am using the default web.Dockerfile. 
However I am running into this error:

`/App/.build/checkouts/SwiftyBeaver/Sources/FileDestination.swift:135:27: error: use of unresolved identifier 'NSFileCoordinator'`

I am using `https://github.com/vapor-community/swiftybeaver-provider` as well (however I the error is from SwiftyBeaver itself). The error seems to be from building for Linux - it builds find locally out of Docker. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Same Issue flagged on SwiftyBeaver Repo: https://github.com/SwiftyBeaver/SwiftyBeaver/issues/392